# PHP MYSQL Do and only if php session variable exists

Tags: php, mysql, variables

i would like my mysql query to be different depending on the content
of a php variable (session) it has to be something like:

```
if ($_SESSION['session_id'] != NULL) { 
   $var1 = "and id = '$_SESSION[session_id]'";
}
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT  field1, field2
FROM    table
WHERE   name = '$_GET[name]' $var1
") or die(mysql_error());
```

which will be: `WHERE name = '$_GET[name]' and id = '$_SESSION[session_id]'`
or: `WHERE name = '$_GET[name]'`

how can i do this? Thanks.

Comment: Vulnerable to injection attacks.  I hope this isn't live.

Comment: Hey @Daedalus, Can you show me the secure way?

Comment: no, this is not live... it's just an example, but why is it vulnerable?

Comment: You should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: The above is mostly a canned response, but it holds true for the above.

Comment: @MrMadMan As to why it is vulnerable, someone could easily put a query into the get variable, and alter it while making the rest of the query invalid.

Comment: @MrMadMan: http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: @MarcB haha ok I get it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are trying to create has some serious (and less serious) problems that you need to fix right away if you ever want to make your site usefull.

First of, dont use `mysql_` function but switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). `mysql` functions have been deprecated.

Also you are inserting user input directly into your query. This causes some serious SQL injection problems. Always make sure to validate and escape user input.

To create a query like you want I'd use:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];

//validate $name according to your choice of mysql provider. EG: mysqli_real_escape_string
//this is just basic validation. make sure you also add other types of validation. If a name is always alphanumeric, make sure you also check that it is before using it.

/*
if you dont validate and I would enter my name like: hugo' OR 1=1 --
I would be able to access any record in your database. And that is just a harmless example.
*/

$query = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE name = '".$name."'"

//for sake of simplicity I assume the id is numeric
if (!empty($_SESSION['session_id']) AND is_numeric($_SESSION['session_id'])) { 
   $query .= " and id = '".$_SESSION['session_id']."'";
}

//exec query
?>
```

Comment: empty isnt just for arrays. And I use `empty` because an Id of 0, which is often used after a log out, should be dismissed also

Comment: Which is why I deleted my comment.

Comment: Although this approach is better than in the question, building SQL by concatenating strings is unnecessarily dangerous -- there are too many opportunities to leave a hole open. Prepared statements are a much better option IMO.